# Formatear moneda, de euro a dolar

Tags: laravel, numberformat

Hola estoy haciendo el carrito de compras y tengo la moneda mostrada en `€`. Por ejemplo tengo un producto que vale 1.250,00 € y también hay otro que puede valer 1,00€.

Bien el sistema que estoy utilizando en laravel para el carrito es shopping cart, y al mandar la moneda al carrito me dice que el formato no es valido. Entonces puedo formatear en el controlador de Euro a Dolar el string??? ya luego le vuelvo a dar formato??

Ejemplo:

Yo en la vista según la opción que elijo imprimo en un div y en un input hidden el valor del producto ya formateado:

```
const formatterEuro = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
   currency: 'EUR'
})
const montoFormat = formatterEuro.formatToParts(data.precio).filter((p) => p.type !== 'currency').map((p) => p.value).join('').trim();
```

Ahora con esto lo imprimo en el value del input hidden, para mandarlo al carrito:

```
var a = $("#valorPrecio").html(); 
document.getElementById("elPrecio").value = a;
console.log(a)
```

De este modo imprimo si es un millar: 1.250,00€ y si no lleva millares 150,00€.

```
Bien cuando mando al carrito hago esto:

public function add(Request $res)
    {
        //dd($precio);
        $add = Cart::add([
            'id' => $res->id, 
            'name' => $res->producto, 
            'qty' => $res->cantidad, 
            'price' => $res->elPrecio, 
            'weight' => 550, 
            'options' => ['imagen' => $res->imagen]]);
        
        $total = Cart::total();
        $contador = Cart::count();
        if($add){
            //dd($add);
            return redirect('carrito')->with( [
                'data' => Cart::content(),
                "contador" => $contador,
                "total" => $total
            ]);
        }
    };
```

Bien la prueba que estoy haciendo, pero no se si es correcto, hago esto al principio de la función.

```
$precio = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $res->elPrecio)));
```

Entonces me llega a la vista del carrito como 1250 o si solo es un euro pues 1. Y luego lo estoy formateando en la vista así:

```
@php $precio = number_format($carrito->price, 2, ',', '.'); @endphp
```

De este modo me imprime: 1.250,00 o si no es millar 1,00

Pero no se si lo estoy haciendo bien

Comment: Muestra el código que tienes para ese proceso por favor. No sé si tu problema es conversión de tipo de moneda o simplemente reemplazar un caracter en un string.

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Si perdonar, ya he ampliado la pregunta. No se porque pregunte así sorry!, @L.Flor ya amplie